# Linphone make a video call with URI Handlers

Tags: linphone

i have to make Linphone call direclty from web page (with href call).
On Google i found this uri `sip:toto@sip.linphone.org?method=call`, with this i can call another account perfeclty but for video call what is the rigth uri? i had try  `..?method=video`  but without succesfull.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a method to differentiate audio call from video call in the SIP URI because whether a call is video or not depends on your "automatically initiate" video policy and on the recipient's "automatically accept" video policy.

Both have to be enabled for a call to be video automatically.

You can enable both this way in your config file:

```
[video]
automatically_initiate=1
automatically_accept=1
```

The other option is to do it in code using VideoActivationPolicy object available from the Core (see [API documentation](https://download.linphone.org/releases/docs/liblinphone/latest/java/org/linphone/core/Core.html#setVideoActivationPolicy-org.linphone.core.VideoActivationPolicy-)).